# How to get last boot times?

Tags: boot, reboot, last

I have a raspberry pi. I have a crontab running and telling it to reboot at mid-day every day (`sudo reboot now`).

Here is the result of `last reboot -F`:

```
myuser@mypiname:~ $ last -F reboot
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970   still running
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970   still running
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970   still running
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Tue Oct 27 12:00:33 2020 (18562+11:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Tue Oct 27 12:00:03 2020 (18562+11:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Mon Oct 26 12:01:00 2020 (18561+11:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Mon Oct 26 12:00:31 2020 (18561+11:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Mon Oct 26 12:00:03 2020 (18561+11:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Mon Oct 26 12:00:03 2020 (18561+11:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Mon Oct 26 12:00:03 2020 (18561+11:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Sun Oct 25 12:00:33 2020 (18560+11:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Sun Oct 25 12:00:03 2020 (18560+11:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Sat Oct 24 12:00:33 2020 (18559+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Sat Oct 24 12:00:04 2020 (18559+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Fri Oct 23 12:00:03 2020 (18558+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Thu Oct 22 12:00:44 2020 (18557+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Thu Oct 22 12:00:11 2020 (18557+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Wed Oct 21 12:00:06 2020 (18556+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Tue Oct 20 12:00:33 2020 (18555+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Tue Oct 20 12:00:04 2020 (18555+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Mon Oct 19 12:00:33 2020 (18554+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Mon Oct 19 12:00:03 2020 (18554+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Sun Oct 18 12:00:04 2020 (18553+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Sat Oct 17 12:00:04 2020 (18552+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Fri Oct 16 12:00:33 2020 (18551+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Fri Oct 16 12:00:03 2020 (18551+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Fri Oct 16 12:00:03 2020 (18551+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Thu Oct 15 12:00:34 2020 (18550+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Thu Oct 15 12:00:04 2020 (18550+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Wed Oct 14 12:00:04 2020 (18549+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Wed Oct 14 12:00:04 2020 (18549+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Wed Oct 14 12:00:04 2020 (18549+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Tue Oct 13 12:00:33 2020 (18548+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Tue Oct 13 12:00:03 2020 (18548+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Mon Oct 12 12:00:36 2020 (18547+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Mon Oct 12 12:00:04 2020 (18547+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Sun Oct 11 12:00:34 2020 (18546+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Sun Oct 11 12:00:04 2020 (18546+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Sat Oct 10 12:00:33 2020 (18545+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Sat Oct 10 12:00:04 2020 (18545+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Fri Oct  9 12:02:03 2020 (18544+10:02)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Fri Oct  9 12:00:04 2020 (18544+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Thu Oct  8 12:00:34 2020 (18543+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Thu Oct  8 12:00:04 2020 (18543+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Wed Oct  7 12:00:33 2020 (18542+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Wed Oct  7 12:00:04 2020 (18542+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Tue Oct  6 12:00:04 2020 (18541+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Mon Oct  5 17:38:18 2020 (18540+15:38)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Mon Oct  5 12:00:04 2020 (18540+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Sun Oct  4 12:00:33 2020 (18539+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Sun Oct  4 12:00:03 2020 (18539+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Sat Oct  3 12:00:04 2020 (18538+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Fri Oct  2 12:00:03 2020 (18537+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Fri Oct  2 12:00:03 2020 (18537+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Thu Oct  1 18:07:11 2020 (18536+16:07)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Thu Oct  1 18:07:11 2020 (18536+16:07)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Thu Oct  1 18:07:11 2020 (18536+16:07)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Thu Oct  1 18:07:11 2020 (18536+16:07)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Thu Oct  1 18:07:11 2020 (18536+16:07)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Thu Oct  1 12:01:00 2020 (18536+10:00)
reboot   system boot  4.19.66-v7+      Thu Jan  1 01:00:01 1970 - Thu Oct  1 12:00:31 2020 (18536+10:00)

wtmp begins Thu Oct  1 10:28:43 2020
```

I unplugged my Raspberry Pi around 2PM today (27/10/2020 13:55:XX) but it does not show here that it had been unplugged (maybe because it is not a reboot).

How do I get last boot times instead of last reboot times? Also, I would like to have "all" the boot times, not only the last.

I tried `last boot -F` but it does not show anything.

Comment: related https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78528/how-to-get-the-reboot-times/94608#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20uptime,date%2Ftime%20as%20it%20boots.

Answer (score 2):

## Getting boot time

The first problem that you will get on the Pi. Is that the boot logs are created before the device gets the time from the network time server. The device has no battery backed clock, so starts at `1970-01-01T00:00` (this is also breaking `who -b`).

The 2nd date in your and my logs look reasonable, but is the shutdown time.

You will need to find a way to log boot times on this device.

### Some ideas

`uptime --since` gives the correct boot time. (It the system, now, has the correct time).

## Boot or re-boot

Next we need to ask, what do you mean by reboot vs boot? There is only boot. However we can look to see if there was a shutdown proceeding it. We can look to see the time difference. We can (and I don't know if this is logged) see what type of shutdown, was it a restart type shutdown?

Comment: I'm not sure myself what's the difference between boot and reboot. In my case, when I unplugged the raspberry pi and plugged it back, the timestamp did not appear in the result of `last -F reboot`. Is it because it's not a reboot?

Comment: Yes the shutdown time is missing. Because it did not shutdown (no opportunity to write the time to the log). Note that this is the shutdown time, not the boot time.

Comment: Indeed, `last -x shutdown` does not show the timestamp I need. Last one is `shutdown system down  4.19.66-v7+      Tue Oct 27 12:00 - 01:00 (-18562+-11:00)` which is before my unplug/plug manip.

Comment: @vinzee yes. Do you understand the answer. It does not solve all the problem, but does highlight what is wrong, and makes a little progress to solving it.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I understand now that what I need to find cannot be found using `last` :)
I will try other monitoring solutions then.

Comment: The problem is not the command. It is that the pi has no real-time-battery-backed-clock. You need to find a way to get the boot time. `uptime --since` gets the most recent. If you need a log of past boot times, then you need another tool. You could write a script to log them. It will have to be run after the time is known.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $ who -b
```

you'll get time of last boot.

Comment: It gives me `1970-01-01 01:00` and gives me only the last one. I would like a list of all boots.

Answer (score 0):

I went for another solution. I don't need the exact second for boots, so I chose to use `cron` to log at reboot:

```bsh
@reboot  echo "Rebooting at $(date)" >> /path/to/some/file
```

It was inspired by the comment from @ctrl-alt-delor.